# OpenCV finds the middle of a red contour (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, contour

My idea is to filter my body with color-keying. If I wear a red t shirt I would like to find the center of the red tshirt with the contours. Is there a good way for this? 
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width = 400)

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of red color in HSV
    lower_red = np.array([0,50,50])
    upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])

    lower_skin = np.array([0, 48, 80])
    upper_skin = np.array([20, 255, 255])
    skin_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_skin, upper_skin)

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only red colors
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    mask = red_mask + skin_mask


    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations = 2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 2)

    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3, 3), 0)
    skin = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(skin, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

    # # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:     
        cv2.drawContours(skin, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Image", skin)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So at the moment I only draw contours of the Tshirt and the skin. But I would like to find the center of the red t shirt contour. Is this possible? Do I have to filter red on its own and do not add it to the skin mask? Maybe my current code is not able to do this, I would be happy for proposes! :)

Answer (score 1):

Find t-shirt using your red mask and `cv2.findContours` and find its center using `cv2.moments(contour)` as described in [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html):

```
for cnt in contours:
    center_x = int(cnt['m10']/cnt['m00'])
    center_y = int(cnt['m01']/cnt['m00'])
```